# Python IDE that can show diagram representation

Tags: python

I want to see how to global variables and local variables i assign get allocated and changes when through the program

Looking for IDE which will be more interactive to show variable assigning and helping the beginners to understand

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).
It has a variable explorer and many more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Spyder. It has a variable explorer.

[image]

You can also try Pycharm. It has a variable explorer.

[image]